# Add dependecies to runtime image with Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, javafx, log4j

I don't know how to add dependency. My module needs Log4j. I added requirement to module info. I added also to gradle dependencies. I can run project, but I can't create custom runtime image.

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.5'
}

group 'eu.sample'
version '2.0'


repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

javafx {
    modules = [ 'javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml' ]
}

mainClassName = "$moduleName/eu.sample.app.Main"

def lin_java_home = hasProperty('org.gradle.java.home') ? getProperty('org.gradle.java.home') : System.getenv('JAVA_HOME')
def lin_fx_jmods = hasProperty('linux.fx.mods') ? getProperty('linux.fx.mods') : System.getenv('PATH_TO_FX_MODS_LIN')

def win_java_home = hasProperty('windows.java.home') ? getProperty('windows.java.home') : System.getenv('JAVA_HOME_WIN')
def win_fx_jmods = hasProperty('windows.fx.mods') ? getProperty('windows.fx.mods') : System.getenv('PATH_TO_FX_MODS_WIN')

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.11.1'
}

task jlink(type: Exec) {
    dependsOn 'clean'
    dependsOn 'jar'

    workingDir 'build'

    if (lin_java_home == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("java_home is not defined.")
    }
    if (lin_fx_jmods == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("fx_jmods is not defined.")
    }
    commandLine "${lin_java_home}/bin/jlink", '--module-path', "libs${File.pathSeparatorChar}${lin_fx_jmods}",
            '--add-modules', "${moduleName}", '--output', "${moduleName}", '--strip-debug',
            '--compress', '2', '--no-header-files', '--no-man-pages'
}

task jlinkWin(type: Exec) {
    dependsOn 'clean'
    dependsOn 'jar'


    workingDir 'build'

    if (win_java_home == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("java_home is not defined.")
    }
    if (win_fx_jmods == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("fx_jmods is not defined.")
    }
    commandLine "${lin_java_home}/bin/jlink", '--module-path', 
            "${win_java_home}/jmods${File.pathSeparatorChar}libs${File.pathSeparatorChar}${win_fx_jmods}",
            '--add-modules', "${moduleName}", '--output', "${moduleName}", '--strip-debug',
            '--compress', '2', '--no-header-files', '--no-man-pages'
}
```

When I fire task jlink I get:

> Error: Module org.apache.logging.log4j not found, required by
>   app

I checked libs directory in build and there is not log4j jar. How to tell gradle to add dependencies to jlink task?

Comment: Why not using a [plugin](https://github.com/beryx/badass-jlink-plugin/)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Problem**

This is what you have in your `jlink` task:

```
'--module-path', "libs${File.pathSeparatorChar}${fx_jmods}"
```

Whats means that you are adding the dependencies from:

- `libs`: basically the jar of your module `helloFX`. This is a result of the `jar` task, that only includes the classes and resources of your project, but not its dependencies.
- `fx_jmods`: That is the path to the JavaFX jmods.

But when you run, you get this error:

> Error: Module org.apache.logging.log4j not found, required by app

The error means that the `module-path` for the `jlink` command is not complete, and it can't resolve all the required dependencies. As mentioned above, we are only including the module.jar and the JavaFX (jmods) jars, but not the `log4j.jar`.

So we need to find a way to add that jar to the module-path.

There are a few possible solutions to include third party dependencies in your custom image.

**Solution 1**

We have to modify the `jlink` task, to include the existing dependencies in our runtime configuration.

The most immediate solution is finding where the logj4 jars are stored by gradle, in the local .gradle repository.

```
'--module-path', "libs${File.pathSeparatorChar}${fx_jmods}: \
   /Users/<user>/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-api/2.11.1/268..a10/log4j-api-2.11.1.jar: \
   /Users/<user>/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core/2.11.1/59..e4/log4j-core-2.11.1.jar"
```

While this solution works, it is not the most convenient, of course, as it depends on local paths from the user.

**Solution 2**

A better solution, can be done adding a task to copy the runtime dependencies, that are resolved directly by gradle, into the `libs` folder like:

```
task libs(type: Copy) {
    into 'build/libs/'
    from configurations.runtime
}
```

and then calling this task from the `jlink` task:

```
task jlink(type: Exec) {
    dependsOn 'clean'
    dependsOn 'jar'
    dependsOn 'libs'
    ...
}
```

If you run `./gradlew jlink` and check the `libs` folder you should find something like this:

```
build/libs/hellofx.jar
build/libs/javafx-base-11.0.1.jar
build/libs/javafx-base-11.0.1-$platform.jar
build/libs/javafx-graphics-11.0.1.jar
build/libs/javafx-graphics-11.0.1-$platform.jar
build/libs/javafx-controls-11.0.1.jar
build/libs/javafx-controls-11.0.1-$platform.jar
build/libs/javafx-fxml-11.0.1.jar
build/libs/javafx-fxml-11.0.1-$platform.jar
build/libs/log4j-api-2.11.1.jar
build/libs/log4j-core-2.11.1.jar
```

where `$platform` is your running platform.

Notice that the `libs` folder now contains *all* the dependencies that are required for the module path, and also that the JavaFX-*-$platform jars *contain* the native libraries, therefore, the jmods are not needed anymore in the module-path option. This will be enough:

```
'--module-path', "libs"
```

so your command line will be:

```
commandLine "${java_home}/bin/jlink", '--module-path', "libs",
        '--add-modules', "${moduleName}", '--output', "${moduleName}", '--strip-debug', '--compress', '2', '--no-header-files', '--no-man-pages'
```

You can run your `jlink` task now successfully.

**Solution 3**

As suggested by @madhead comment, you can use another plugin for the `jlink` task: the *so called* [badass-jlink-plugin](https://github.com/beryx/badass-jlink-plugin).

Modify your build to something like:

```
plugins {
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.5'
    id 'org.beryx.jlink' version '2.1.8'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.11.1'
}

javafx {
    modules = ['javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml']
}

mainClassName = "${moduleName}/eu.sample.app.Main"

jlink {
    options = ['--strip-debug', '--compress', '2', '--no-header-files', '--no-man-pages']
    launcher {
        name = 'helloFX'
    }
}
```

Note also that the plugin has an option to create image for other platforms (see [targetPlatform](https://badass-jlink-plugin.beryx.org/releases/latest/#_methods)).

**EDIT about log4j**

As mentioned in the comments, the `log4j` dependency doesn't play well with modules yet. There is an [open issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/LOG4J2/issues/LOG4J2-2438?filter=allopenissues) at the Apache Issue tracker:

> Currently based on the given automatic modules you can't use log4j-core in a project where you like to use jlink to produce a runtime image.

I've added this to my main class:

```
LogManager.getLogger(MainApp.class).info("hellofx!");
```

and I've added the `log4j2.xml` file to `src/main/resources`.

Running `./gradlew run`, works:

```
> Task :run
18:24:26.362 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  eu.sample.app.Main - hellofx!
```

But, running jlink from Solution 2, creates the custom image, I can verify that the xml file is included, but when running from the image I get:

```
build/hellofx/bin/java -m hellofx/eu.sample.app.Main
ERROR StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation. \
    Please add log4j-core to the classpath. Using SimpleLogger to log to the console...
```

And as mentioned, running jlink with the plugin from Solution 3 <s>fails at the `createMergedModule` task</s>:

```
 error: package org.apache.logging.log4j.spi is not visible
   provides org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.Provider with org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jProvider;
```

[See EDIT(2), this has been fixed since version 2.1.9]

*Alternative*

At this point, a possible alternative could be use Slf4j instead. There is a [sample](https://github.com/copper-engine/copper-modular-demo) listed from the plugin documentation that uses it successfully.

In summary this is required:

Gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.8.0-beta2'
    compile('ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.3.0-alpha4') {
        exclude module: "activation"
    }
}
```

Module-info:

```
requires org.slf4j;
requires ch.qos.logback.classic;
requires java.naming;
```

Main class:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MainApp.class);

...
logger.info("hellofx!");
```

`logging.properties` from [here](https://github.com/copper-engine/copper-modular-demo/blob/master/src/main/resources/logging.properties) and `logback.xml` from [here](https://github.com/copper-engine/copper-modular-demo/blob/master/src/main/resources/logback.xml), with your main class.

Both running `./gradlew` run or `./gradlew jlink`, and `build/image/bin/HelloFX` work, and the message is logged to the console.

**EDIT (2)**

After [reporting](https://github.com/beryx/badass-jlink-plugin/issues/14) the issue to the badass-jlink-plugin's issue tracker, this was solved, and since version 2.1.19 it should work fine creating a custom image.

Since `log4j` is multi-release jar, there is one thing required:

```
plugins {
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.5'
    id 'org.beryx.jlink' version '2.1.9'
}

...

jlink {
    options = ['--strip-debug', '--compress', '2', '--no-header-files', '--no-man-pages']
    launcher {
       name = 'helloFX'
    }
    forceMerge('log4j-api')     // <---- this is required for Log4j
}
```

See a full working sample [here](https://github.com/beryx-gist/badass-jlink-example-log4j2-javafx).

Comment: Second solution seems to be more elegant and clear. I tried it. But I got error during `Task :createMergedModule`. Stacktrace says: `package ....log4j.spi is not visible provides ....log4j.spi.Provider with  ....log4j.core.impl.Log4jProvider` and `ackage ....log4j.message is not visible provides .log4j.message.ThreadDumpMessage.ThreadInfoFactory with ....log4j.core.message.ExtendedThreadInfoFactory; (package ....log4j.message is declared in module ....log4j, but module eu.sample.merged.module does not read it)` I am trying to solve this.

Comment: I know, I noticed it too. I've used this plugin without issues a few times, but with non-modular dependencies it might have some issues, as it tries to create a merged module over them...

Comment: I've edited my answer, with these issues. I've also added a working sample with Slf4j.

Comment: Yes, solution 3 and alternative is working. Thank you for your time and very detailed answer.

Comment: Good to know it works for you. I've filed an [issue](https://github.com/beryx/badass-jlink-plugin/issues/14) to see if the `jlink` plugin can do something to make Log4j work.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/beryx-gist/badass-jlink-example-log4j2-javafx) is an example project using the `jlink`plugin with log4j 2.11.1.
See also my comments on the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/beryx/badass-jlink-plugin/issues/14#issuecomment-447351574).

Comment: @siordache Great! That was fast. I've just tested and it works fine for me. I'll edit my answer to include the new version of your plugin.