# How to turn JAVA FX Application to real application?

Tags: javafx

I have a JavaFX Application which is built in Eclipse IDE and runs fine in my Environment since I also have the JAVA FX SDK connected to the environment. How can I have my Application run on any computer. I want to know how or is it possible for a JAVA FX Application to run on any computer even without the JAVA FX SDK. I have made my project into a JAR File however I can only run my program using Command Prompt since I run the Jar File, also having to include the VM Environments to have the program run. What steps can I take to have my Application to turn in an application which a normal user can run on their computer. I have looked over this [Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54199352/how-to-make-an-exe-and-an-app-from-a-javafx-11-application-using-netbeans) which uses a Launch 4j to turn a jar into a .exe. What is the significance that the file being a .exe? Will it run on a computer without Java FX? My question is mainly on how will my program usability be affected since it uses JAVA FX?

Comment: [packaging resources are in the JavaFX tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javafx/info).

Answer (score 0):

Try `jpackage` to generate native bundle if you are using java module system.

Or `jlink` to generate a custom jre and write a start script.