# Is there a way to address module path to the modules inside runnable jar package in JVM options?

Tags: java, gradle, javafx, jar, runtime

1-I created a jar package contains my module and also javafx modules inside itself
how can i address --module-path to the javafx modules inside my jar package instead of external javafx library in JVM options to run my jar?
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WaBn0.png)

2-I also used gradle with my project is there a way to create a jar contains javafx modules by build.gradle file without creating artifacts in project structure?
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FHbZ.png)
JDK 9 above and gradle 5 above

Comment: Are you trying to merge your own module-info with the module-info for javafx classes that you added to your jar or are you trying to refer to the `javafx-swt.jar` entry in your jar file?

Comment: I wanna address javafx modules that are inside my jar to the JVM Options

Comment: You appear to have extracted the JavaFX classes (except for those in `javafx-swt.jar`) and placed them in your application's JAR file. For a non-modular application this should work, possibly requiring a few modifications. However, as I understand it there can only be one module per JAR file. As you can see in your image there's only one `module-info.class` remaining. This means you can't reference the JavaFX modules embedded in your JAR file because the JavaFX modules no longer exist; all the JavaFX code is now part of _your_ module.

Comment: so how can i create a runnable jar without reffering to the external javafx library? i wanna create an executable jar which executes just by one click not specify external library by  module-path in JVM options

Comment: You could make your application non-modular. The JavaFX modules can still be used from the classpath so long as your main-class is not a subclass of `Application`.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54065502/6395627) goes into more detail. Unfortunately, there's no support for executable modular JAR files. The answer I linked to, however, does give options for a self-contained Java application which are compatible with modules. The should-be-coming-soon `jpackage` tool even allows for you to create native executables.