# How to compile a JAR file in command line from JavaFX-based java files in jdk-12.0.2 as it does not have ant-javafx.jar?

Tags: javafx, ant

I was using NetBeans with **jdk-1.8.0** to compile JavaFX-based files for a desktop application. Now I have updated to **jdk-12.0.2** and I need to make JAR files from those Java files without NetBeans. I found that "jdk-12.0.2/lib" does not contain "ant-javafx.jar" also. Oracle documentaion states about **jdk-1.8.0**-based JavaFX handling. I am confused.

I appreciate any help so that I may make JAR file in commandline (with the **manifest** file) in **jdk-12.0.2** in ubuntu. Thanks a lot.

Comment: May help you: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/

Comment: @Slaw Thanks for the info. I did not know that Javafx is now separate and working through gluon project. That means if someone takes my javafx based code in other laboratory then (s)he has to load javafx separately to run my code?

Comment: Yes, if using OracleJDK or OpenJDK one would need to pull in the JavaFX libraries just like any other dependency. Other distributors (e.g. [Zulu Community™](https://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu-community/)) may offer JDK packages that also include the OpenJFX libraries. Note that some of the JavaFX modules (e.g. `javafx.graphics`) have platform-specific native code.

Comment: Note for _development_, if your project uses a build tool such as Maven or Gradle then pulling in dependencies is vastly simplified. For _deployment_, however, you'll have to ship the JavaFX libraries with your application. There are different ways to do this; both [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53453212/how-to-deploy-a-javafx-11-desktop-application-with-a-jre) and [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54063041/package-a-non-modular-javafx-application?) give more details (also browse both Q&A's linked questions).

Comment: @Slaw, thank you very much for your clear explanation.