# How to export JavaFX 11 Project into Jar?

Tags: java, javafx, jar

I spent hours googling today most solutions are out of date. 
I use eclipse on Window the project complies, but I am unable to make it a standalone application without:

```
java --module-path C:\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib\  --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.graphics,javafx.web -jar Jar.jar
```

What are the ways I can export JavaFX 11 Projects into an executable jar without the need to link it to javafx-sdk-11.0.2 after export?

Thanks.

Comment: Related Q&As: [How to deploy a JavaFX 11 Desktop application with a JRE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53453212/), [JavaFX 11 : Create a jar file with Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52569724/), [Maven Shade JavaFX runtime components are missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52653836/), and [Package a non-modular JavaFX application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54063041/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may build this project with `Maven` from your IDE, including necessary dependencies:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
    <version>11.0.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
    <version>11.0.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
    <version>11.0.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
    <version>11.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

Build your project with [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) and use that kind of `pom.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
         http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>tld.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifact</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>artifact</name>
    <description>My artifact</description>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <javafx.main.class>your.package.YourJavaFxAppMainClass</javafx.main.class>
        <main.class>your.package.YourMainClass</main.class>
    </properties>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.2</version>
            <classifier>win</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    
    <build>
        <!-- Jar's final name -->
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Build source and target -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <!--<arg>--add-modules=java.smartcardio</arg>-->
                    </compilerArgs>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>${javafx.main.class}</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Distributable archive building -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <!-- Main class -->
                            <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <!--  Includes project's dependencies -->
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

You have to provide two application classes.

The Javafx one:

```java
public class YourJavaFxAppMainClass extends javafx.application.Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        // ...
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
    // ...
}
```

The other which is used to run your program from your IDE (for instance IntelliJ):

```java
public class YourMainClass {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        YourJavaFxAppMainClass.main(args);
    }
}
```

Then you can package your jar using `mvn clean package` and run it with `java -jar target/artifact.jar`.