# How to package JavaFX Executable JAR without using a .exe?

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I am trying to put a executable JAR onto different computer where I cannot run any .exe files. After completing my project on Eclipse with JavaFX 11, I tried exporting the code as an executable JAR. When I run the JAR on the computer that wrote the program nothing happens. As I understand it, all of the necessary JavaFX files are not being packaged into the executable JAR thus prevents the program from running. My question is how do I include all the necessary JavaFX files into the executable JAR without the need of a .exe installer? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Getting Started with JavaFX > JavaFX and Eclipse > Modular from IDE > 6. Create a custom runtime image](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-Intellij) will help you.

Comment: When I export the example I still have the same problem. It runs just fine but once it becomes a .jar on my desktop it wont run.

Comment: Related Q&As: [How to deploy a JavaFX 11 Desktop application with a JRE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53453212/), [JavaFX 11 : Create a jar file with Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52569724/), [Maven Shade JavaFX runtime components are missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52653836/), and [Package a non-modular JavaFX application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54063041/). (note some deal with executable files, others with fat/uber jars)